# No metadata object returned from Nest API

Tags: ios, nest-api

Since Nest's Developer API 1.1, there is the concept of client versioning, which enables the developer to find out if a user has accepted changes in the permissions the client has proposed.

For example: my app didn't need read/write access to Away (version 1), but will in the near future (version 2). By examining the `client_version` value in the `metadata` object, the developer will know if access to Away is available and have the app and its UI act accordingly.

From Nest's developer documentation:

> Metadata is additional information that is provided when you make a
>   call to the root-level endpoint.
>   (https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-overview#client_version)

More specifically elsewhere:

> With a root-level call, the data model will change to include the metadata object.
>   (https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/metadata)

By root-level call, I assume something along these lines is meant (Objective-C, but pretty straightforward):

```
mainBase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://developer-api.nest.com/"];
[mainBase authWithCredential:accessToken withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, id data){

  [mainBase observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) { 
    NSLog(@"response from root end-point: %@", snapshot.value);
  }];
}];
```

This is somewhat condensed, but clearly, a call is being made to /, which returns all available thermostats, smoke_co_alarms and structures (as example documentation shows is to be expected). However, no metadata key is returned.

Am I making the wrong call? Or is there some other reason no metadata is returned?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue returning the meta data which has since been resolved.  Please try again.